# Micro-Service Applications in Java

Tags: rest, war, microservices

When UI is supplied by Angular web application, the responsibility of the other micro service applications gets limited to supplying JSONS. But they still need to support ReST paths and cannot be a monolithic giant. Meaning, can't just make those as JARs and bind it as dependency to some WAR app. Is there a better way to do this than keeping the WAR applications that are just going to supply JSONs as UI less WARs for the sake of making sure that they are not mixed up?